# filter based on groupwise count

Tags: r, dplyr

```
> diamonds %>% group_by(color) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  color     n
  <ord> <int>
1 G     11292
2 E      9797
3 F      9542
4 H      8304
5 D      6775
6 I      5422
7 J      2808
```

I would like to filter diamonds to exclude any groups where their total count is less than 6K.

I was thinking I could group by and `nest()` then `unnest()` but wondered if there was a less code more elegant way using a window function to filter on? I was reading docs [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/window-functions.html) but could not immediately see a way to filter based on group counts.

How could I filter diamonds to exclude rows containing color I or J since I and J have a total count each of less than 6K?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can directly use `filter` after the grouping step

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% 
      group_by(color) %>% 
      filter(n() > 6000)
```